# Using Automappper to map to methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, automapper

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 2 application in C# and i am successfully using Automapper to map values back and forth between ViewModels and business objects.

In addition to several explicit properties, my business objects wrap a dictionary as a catch all for properties that aren't explicitly defined.  Something similar to:

```
public class MyBusinessObject {
    public void SetExtraPropertyValue<T>(string key, T value) { 
        // ...
      }
    public T GetExtraPropertyValue<T>(string key, T defaultValue) {
        // ...
      }
}
```

In my ViewModel, I have the freedom to create any properties I want, but I cannot modify the business objects.

So let's say I create a view model like this:

```
class MyViewModel {
  public string CustomProp { get; set; }
}
```

and the value I want to store and retrieve will need to use

```
businessModelInstance.SetExtraPropertyValue("CustomProp", newVal);
```

and

```
businessModelInstance.GetExtraPropertyValue("CustomProp");
```

I have problems going both directions.
First, when going from the MyBusinessObject to the MyViewModel, I thought it should be simple to do in my custom Automapper profile:

```
CreateMap<MyBusinessObject, MyViewModel>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomProp, 
             opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.GetExtraPropertyValue("CustomProp", "")));
```

However, `MyBusinessObject.CustomProp` is never populated, though other properties are.
Secondly, I don't know how to configure getting a value from `MyViewModel.CustomProp` to calling `MyBusinessObject.SetExtraPropertyValue`.

- Is there a way to accomplish this
  mapping with Automapper?
- Is there a completely different attack that I
  should be trying?
- Do I have to resort to manual mapping in my controller? For example,    `MyBusinessObject.SetExtraPropertyValue("CustomProp",
  MyViewModel.CustomProp)`

---

**UPDATE**:  Here is my solution based on @Patrick Steele's suggestions:
I added a custom attribute to the view model properties that i wanted to map to extra property keys. A custom TypeConverter uses reflection to find these attributes and map properties appropriately.

```
public class ItemExtraPropertyConverter : ITypeConverter<MyViewModel, MyBusinessObject>
{
    public MyBusinessObject Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var destination = context.DestinationValue as MyBusinessObject;
        if (destination == null )
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Destination type is not of type MyBusinessObject");

        foreach (var property in context.SourceType.GetProperties())
            foreach (var attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ExtraPropertyAttribute>())
            {
                var key = attribute.Key;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                    key = property.Name;
                destination.SetExtraPropertyValue(key, property.GetValue(context.SourceValue, null));
            }

        return destination;
    }
}

public class ExtraPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ExtraPropertyAttribute()
    {
    }
    public ExtraPropertyAttribute(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    [ExtraProperty]
    public string CustomProp { get; set; }

    [ExtraProperty("OtherPropertyValue")]
    public string CustomProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the custom profile class's configure method:

```
CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyBusinessObject>()
            .ConvertUsing<ItemExtraPropertyConverter>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that something is wrong with your GetExtraPropertyValue and SetExtraPropertyValue implementations.  I threw together a quick test and the mapping you provided above worked as expected.  Here's the implementation I used for the test:

```
public class MyBusinessObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> extraProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void SetExtraPropertyValue<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        extraProperties.Add(key, value);
    }
    public T GetExtraPropertyValue<T>(string key, T defaultValue)
    {
        if (extraProperties.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)extraProperties[key];
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look in to it.  you're right, the simple test worked for me.  must be something stupid in my code - that's something i can debug.  The bigger problem for me is how to go the other direction - mapping properties on the view model to the appropriate dictionary entry on the business object.  I still haven't been able to come up with a solution...Any ideas there?

Comment: I think a custom type converter work work for that.  A little bit of reflection to query your view model for all of its public properties.  Use the property name as the key for you calls to SetPropertyValue.  Just realize that reflection does have a perf impact -- you'll have to decide if it's an acceptable impact.

Comment: This is not a high volume site (an adminisration site) so reflection is not a problem.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.